# Python MySQL Connector - cursor won't commit()

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have python (3.4) code and the cursor just won't commit it to the database. I can commit the changes if I type them in manually through the MySQL client (so I'm sure that I have `UPDATE` permissions on the relevant table). This code just updates a table with info from a csv file:

```
#!/bin/python3.4
import mysql.connector
import csv
import sys

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='me', password=sys.argv[1] , host="localhost", database="mydb")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
csvfile = open("products.csv", 'r', newline='')
products = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)

update_product= ("UPDATE products SET "
    "ticket_price = %(ticket_price)s, "
    "quantity_ordered = %(quantity_ordered)s "
    "WHERE product_code = \"%(product_code)s\";"
)
for row in products:
    data = {
        "product_code":row["product_code"],
        "ticket_price":row["ticket_price"],
        "quantity_ordered":row["quantity_ordered"]
    }
    cursor.execute(update_product, data)
    print(row["product_code"] + " quantity_ordered: " + row["quantity_ordered"])
# Commit to the database
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
csvfile.close()
cnx.close()
```

As it's a prepared statement, I don't believe I can retrieve the actual SQL string executed (but calling `print(update_product % data)` lets me look at how the statement is supposed to appear). From manually copy-pasting into the python interpreter, I believe the SQL is OK (`cursor.fetchwarnings()` doesn't complain). The input data is good; the print statement reads correctly. It just won't commit - all the info in the database remains zero for those rows. I've compared this script to an almost identical one that works, and nothing seems different. I've also tried `cnx.autocommit = True`, which doesn't work either.

Anyone know how what's wrong, or how to get the `cursor.execute()` and `connector.commit()` return statuses so I can debug? [The API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) doesn't seem to mention, and testing leads me to believe that these methods don't actually return a value. I feel a little blind because of this - I'm supposed to call a method, and pray something happens?

**Edit:**
Out of frustration, I've just generated an SQL file using `print(update_product % data)`. The database accepts it just fine. I can also update the `products` table with static values via python, but not dynamic ones.

Comment: Kind of off topic but is there any reason that you're not using one of Python's web application frameworks, i.e. Django?

Comment: Lack of time and help ;) It's definitely happening over the next 6 months.

Comment: I understand that it requires some time and assistance but learning Django is something that you should commit to. What you're doing right now is done very easily using Django models. So you're effectively reinventing the wheel right now, not to mention that your manual approach isn't scalable. There's a really help step by step tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ that provides more than enough help with getting started with Django.

Comment: The code looks correct and if you don't get any errors, then the rows should be committed to the database. `commit` doesn't return any statuses or errors; when you get there, the database must be in a state where it can commit.

Comment: OK, but how then do you verify that the state is ready to commit?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the python's .commit() return true if the transaction is committed or false if there is an error(i.e.) a rollback.
So you can do something like this:

Instead of just having cx.close;

```
myVariable = cx.close
if(myVariable == true)
    print 'Transaction committed'  //Or whatever action you want to perform

else if(myVariable == false)
    print 'Rollback occurred'   //Or whatever action you want to perform
```

Then you can check the printed statement to know what happened

Comment: It seems `mysql.connector.cursor.execute()` and `mysql.connector.connection.commit()` both return None - i.e. don't return...